# Tensorflow mixed_precision error `x` and `y` must have the same dtype, got tf.float16 != tf.float32

Tags: tensorflow

***mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy="mixed_float16")*** gives an error when I add this line

**error** =

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 5 #mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy="float32")
> 6 input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
> ----> 7 base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
> 8 base_model.trainable = False # freeze base model layers
> 9
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py
> in EfficientNetB0(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape,
> pooling, classes, classifier_activation, **kwargs)
> 559       classes=classes,
> 560       classifier_activation=classifier_activation,
> --> 561       **kwargs)
> 562
> 563
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py
> in EfficientNet(width_coefficient, depth_coefficient, default_size,
> dropout_rate, drop_connect_rate, depth_divisor, activation,
> blocks_args, model_name, include_top, weights, input_tensor,
> input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation)
> 332     # original implementation.
> 333     # See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49930 for more details
> --> 334     x = x / tf.math.sqrt(IMAGENET_STDDEV_RGB)
> 335
> 336   x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 151     except Exception as e:
> 152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> --> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 154     finally:
> 155       del filtered_tb
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/tf_op_layer.py
> in handle(self, op, args, kwargs)
> 105         isinstance(x, keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
> 106         for x in tf.nest.flatten([args, kwargs])):
> --> 107       return TFOpLambda(op)(*args, **kwargs)
> 108     else:
> 109       return self.NOT_SUPPORTED
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
> 66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> ---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 68     finally:
> 69       del filtered_tb
>
> TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer
> "tf.math.truediv_3" (type TFOpLambda).
>
> `x` and `y` must have the same dtype, got tf.float16 != tf.float32.
>
> Call arguments received by layer "tf.math.truediv_3" (type
> TFOpLambda):   • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3),
> dtype=float16)   • y=tf.Tensor(shape=(3,), dtype=float32)   •
> name=None

**this is code =**

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Create base model
mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy="mixed_float16")

input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False # freeze base model layers


# Create Functional model 
inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_layer")
# Note: EfficientNetBX models have rescaling built-in but if your model didn't you could have a layer like below
# x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False) # set base_model to inference mode only
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="pooling_layer")(x)
x = layers.Dense(len(class_names))(x) # want one output neuron per class 
# Separate activation of output layer so we can output float32 activations
outputs = layers.Activation("softmax", dtype=tf.float32, name="softmax_float32")(x) 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", # Use sparse_categorical_crossentropy when labels are *not* one-hot
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

When I change this line with **float32 instead of mixed_float16**,like
this  **mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy="float32")** the
error goes away. I want to use Mixed_precision, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi @sfdsfdsgfgsfsgfsgfsgf, please try again in the most recent TF-Nightly version as this issue has been resolved in it. Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/58c4b337604c2b866d1b2da669a96b46/untitled195.ipynb#scrollTo=xlHQN_VwaKpA). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will fix if you change your TensorFlow version, I faced with this issue when downgraded my TensorFlow from 2.11.0 to 2.9.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).